# Empty partition not empty

Tags: partition

I made a new ext4 partition of 46.6 GiB using gparted an formatted it.

When I mounted it, the file manager shows me "43.2 GiB free of 45.6 GiB".

Why is some space missing, that is still about 3.4GiB?

Comment: Does https://serverfault.com/questions/282317/disk-space-overhead-in-ext4 answer your question?